# C question: If I pass the address of a variable to a function that modifies it is there a guarantee that the variable will be "reloaded" after return?

Tags: c, performance, volatile

I have a lot of code that used to be similar to this:

```
int num = 15;  

if(callback)  
  callback(&num);  /* this function may or may not change the value of num */  

if(num == 15)  /* I assumed num did not need to be volatile and is reloaded */  
  do_something();  
else  
  do_something_else();
```

However I now have more complicated structs and pointers to them:

```
struct example { int x,y,z; };  
struct example eg, eg2, *peg;   
int whatever;  
char fun;  

struct variables { struct example **ppeg; int *whatever; char *fun; };  
struct variables myvars;  

peg = &eg;  
myvars.ppeg = &peg;  
myvars.whatever = &whatever;  
myvars.fun = &fun;  
[...]  
peg->x = 15;  

if(callback)  
  callback(&myvars);  /* this function may or may not change the variables */  

if(peg->x == 15)  /* Can I assume that x is "reloaded" ? */  
  do_something();  
else  
  do_something_else();
```

Believe it or not this is still overly simplified. Now obviously I could use volatile, I assume I could do something like this to force a reload:

```
if(*(volatile int *)&peg->x == 15)
```

Does that guarantee a reload? In other words would I then later be able to write simply if(peg->x) knowing that the one volatile cast had already "reloaded" the variable?

The issue is speed as my function could be called continually, millions of times. It is of course much much more intricate than above. I wonder if it would be necessary or preferable to have the callback signal if it modifies the variables, and if there would be some way to handle that. I'm dealing with dozens of variables in the struct and I don't want them to be "reloaded" unless necessary.

Also, does the C99 standard have insight on either of my two pseudo samples, for example to guarantee that after a function that the variables are "reloaded" (I don't know the right word). Or is this issue compiler and optimization level specific? I did test some other similar watered down samples with gcc at -O0 and -O3 and I did not see a difference in either case (in all cases variables had their proper value).

**Thanks everyone!**

EDIT 11/24/2010 1PM EST: To address the comments on what I mean by "reloading" I meant if the compiler is caching the variable (in a register or other memory space for example) before the function call will it still access the same cached variable after the function call, rather than the (possibly) updated variable.
Also compilers can loop hoist to remove variables from the loop that do not change. Like if I have peg->x, rather than access peg->x each time in the loop could the compiler determine there are no other accesses even if the callback is passed &peg? If I have code like this:

```
peg = &eg;  
while(1)  
{  
  if(!peg->x)  
    if(callback)  
      callback(peg);  

  if(!peg->x)  
    peg->x = 20;  

  if(peg == &eg)  
    peg = &eg2;  
  else  
    break;  
}
```

So could the compiler optimize it like this for example:

```
while(1)  
{  
  if(!peg->x)  
  {  
    if(callback)  
      callback(peg);  

    peg->x = 20;  
  }  

  if(peg == &eg)  
    peg = &eg2;  
  else  
    break;  
}
```

or could it optimize it like this:

```
{  
  int someregister;  
  peg = &eg;  
  someregister = peg->x;  

  if(!someregister)  
    if(callback)  
      callback(peg);  

  if(!someregister)  
    peg->x = 20;  

  peg = &eg2;  
  someregister = peg->x;  

  if(!someregister)  
    if(callback)  
      callback(peg);  

  if(!someregister)  
    peg->x = 20;  
}
```

EDIT 11/24/2010 1:45PM EST: Here's another example. The callback could change the pointer to itself.

```
if(psomestruct->callback)  
{  
  psomestruct->callback(psomestruct); /* this callback could change the pointer to itself */  
  if(psomestruct->callback) /* will the compiler optimize this statement out? */  
    psomestruct->callback(psomestruct);  
}
```

Comment: There's no need to worry about variable being reloaded, why do you worry about it?

Comment: Yes. Please clarify what you mean by reloading of a variable. It is terribly confusing.

Comment: Could these variables be modified 'externally' (i.e. by threads or other processes)?

Comment: Judging by the following link, I think when the OP says 'reloaded' he is talking about whether the optimizer may re-use a value inappropriately: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Hi and thanks for your comments. When I say reloaded I mean the variable if cached before the function call is it still cached after the function call, assuming that if it's not it must be "reloaded." Not the right terminology I guess. Threads and other processes do not have access to the variable. My function is in a DLL and accepts a callback that could modify some of my function's variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is **not** allowed to "cache" the value of a variable across function calls that may modify it, *as long as you don't invoke any undefined behaviour*.  Particularly relevant instances of undefined behaviour in this context are:

- modifying a variable that was declared `const`; and
- modifying a variable through an lvalue of incompatible type that is not `unsigned char`.

So, for example, if you have:

```
void modifier(int *a)
{
    *a += 10;
}
```

then this will always work:

```
int i = 5;
modifier(&i);
if (i == 15)
    puts("OK");
```

However, this **may not**:

```
const int i = 5;
modifier((int *)&i);
if (i == 15)
    puts("OK");
```

The same applies to your more complicated examples.  As your examples show, the static analysis required to determine if a function can or cannot modify a given variable can be quite complex.  Compilers are required to be conservative in this case, which often means in practice that once you have taken the address of a variable, the optimisations that can be done around that variable are quite limited.

---

**Addendum:**

This is covered by the C standard, but it does not take the (futile) approach of trying to list every possible optimisation and declare whether it is allowed or disallowed.  Instead, the C standard says (§5.1.2.3 in C99):

> The semantic descriptions in this
>   International Standard describe the
>   behavior of an abstract machine in
>   which issues of optimization are
>   irrelevant.

In other words, the C standard describes an abstract machine that works in a straightforward manner, and any optimisations must ensure that any program that runs correctly on the C abstract machine also run correctly under those optimisations.

Modifying an object (even through a deeply nested pointer within a function call) is a *side-effect*.  In the C abstract machine, all side-effects are complete by the next *sequence point* (there is a sequence point at the end of every expression, for example after the call to `callback()` in your example).  This is also detailed in §5.1.2.3.  Since objects in the C abstract machine have only one value at one time, after the modification is complete any subsequent reads of the object must read the new value.

Thus there is no need for any `ignore_any_variables_previously_in_registers()` - under the C abstract machine, there *is* no concept of caching variable in registers (or indeed, "registers" at all).

If you *know* that a particular variable stored deeply within your nested structs is not modified by the function call, and you want to allow it to be cached across that function call, simply create a local variable to explicitly cache it - exactly as per your example with `someregister`.  The compiler will use a register for `someregister` if it is appropriate.

To address your new examples, the compiler is not allowed to perform those optimisations you suggest.  If it knows nothing about the function assigned to the function pointer `->callback`, it must assume that it can change *any* variable whose address is possibly aliased with a pointer available to `->callback()`.  In practice, this tended to mean that only local variables whose address had not been taken could be assumed to be safe.  The `restrict` keyword was introduced in C99 to allow the programmer to make further guarantees to the optimiser about such aliasing.

Comment: Thanks caf. Is this covered in any C standard? Can it be guaranteed that after the function returns any variable previously cached in a register is "reloaded" or "re-cached" or whatever it's called? My structs are nested, much more complicated than my examples and I'd like to think I'm smarter than the compiler at determining whether or not variables will be modified. I wonder whether it is necessary for some kind of command after returning from a function like ignore_any_variables_previously_in_registers(); to force out any variables cached in a register... or even if that's necessary. Thanks

Comment: @Anonymous Question Guy: No, it's not necessary to explicitly ask for cached variables to be reloaded (absent multiple threads, which is entirely outside the realm of standard C).  Such a request is typically called a "compiler barrier", by the way.  I have updated my answer with an addendum to more completely answer your comment.

Comment: Thanks caf, you have answered my question and I have clicked the check mark next to your answer. I have also enjoyed reading your other answers to different questions. Damn transputers and their negative address space! Have a good thanksgiving guys

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as "reloading" a variable. You can omit the `volatile`, you will still get what you want.

I think you are seeing a problem where none exists.

Comment: Yeah my terminology is way off. I edited the question to better express what I mean. If a variable is cached in a register before a function call will that same variable still be cached in a register after a function call, and assuming the function had changed the variable that would be a big problem as the cached variable would be incorrect.

Comment: @Anonymous Question Guy: I understood your question. My answer stands. You don't have to bother with things like caches / registers in the scope of the C language. (It would be a real bother if you had to, as CPUs are vastly different in this regard.)